# How can I get the object on which the tween in acting inside the onComplete callback function in Phaser.io?

Tags: phaser-framework

I'm adding the following tween on multiple items, inside a loop. What I want is to kill each item after the tween completes. To do this I'm wondering how to get the reference to the object on which the tween is acting inside the onComplete callback function. Thanks in advance. :)

```
    var tween = game.add.tween(item.scale).to({
        x: 1.3,
        y: 1.3
    }, 100).to({
        x: 1,
        y: 1
    }, 100).start();
    tween.onComplete.add(function(){
        //item.kill(); Need to get the object of the tween to kill here!!
    }, this);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first value onComplete contains is the target of the tween:

`tween.onComplete.add(function(sprite, tween) { sprite.kill(); }, this);`

The second is a reference to the Tween object itself.

Answer (score 0):

So I came up with an alternative solution. I thought I share it with everyone. Its pretty cool and achieved thanks to closures. :)

1. Pass the item(from the parent scope) to another function which will handle setting up the tween and adding the onComplete callback.
2. Inside the onComplete callback function directly refer the item which is now in the local scope.

This way passing the item into another function, which originally was in a loop in a parent function, now has its own scope and the tween inside that scope can readily manipulate the item.

Here is a code snippet that might help:

```
killEm: function(){
   for(var i = 0; i < 10; i++){
       var item = getItem(i);
       this.animateAndKill(item);
   }
},
animateAndKill(item){
       var tween = game.add.tween(item.scale).to({
          x: 1.3,
          y: 1.3
       }, 100).to({
          x: 1,
          y: 1
       }, 100).start();
       tween.onComplete.add(function(){
         item.kill(); //Local item, you are mine now!! :)
       }, this);
}
```

Each time the loop runs in the first function a separate scope is created by the second function and each scope is given an item and a tween with access to that item. Now I can directly kill that item with out worrying about how to get a reference to the target in the onComplete callback. That was fun!! :)

Comment: The 2nd parameter to onComplete (and any Phaser signal / event for that matter) is the context in which the callback is invoked. You can use this to avoid having to ever create a closure.

Comment: I might have used an older version of Phaser, but that actually did not work for me. Which is why I sorted out this method. The first parameter to the callback function in the onComplete took a Array of Point(x y) objects and the second parameter was undefined. And the context that gets passed into the onComplete is actually the game itself.